# How to use an OR condition in c:if in Facelets

Tags: jsf, jstl, facelets

How can I use an OR condition in `<c:if>` in Facelets? I need to check for privlage if it is 3 or 2 or 5.

```
 <c:if test="#{Privlage=='3'or '2' or '5'}" >
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just follow the same logic as in normal Java:

```
if (privilege.equals("3") || privilege.equals("2") || privilege.equals("5"))
```

Thus, so:

```
<c:if test="#{privilege == '3' || privilege == '2' || privilege == '5'}">
```

You can use `eq` instead of `==` and `or` instead of `||` in EL.

```
<c:if test="#{privilege eq '3' or privilege eq '2' or privilege eq '5'}">
```

If you're on EL 3.0, then you can make use of new ability to declare inline collections via the new `#{[...]}` syntax for lists and `#{{...}}` syntax for sets. So, the below Java equivalent:

```
List<String> privileges = Arrays.asList("3", "2", "5");
if (privileges.contains(privilege))
```

Can in EL 3.0 be done like:

```
<c:if test="#{['3','2','5'].contains(privilege)}">
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Operators in EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)
- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Operations on Collection objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el004.htm)

Comment: Thanks. you are always there to help :)

Comment: what's the difference between ${} and #{}?

Comment: In Facelets, nothing. In JSP, anything.